# How to make circle at background?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

As show in the design I want to add this type circle for background but doesn't know how to do that? How can I achieve this circle background image:
[image]

This is how other content look on it
[image]

This is code snipt-

```
Container(
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  decoration:BoxDecoration(
  shape: BoxShape.circle,
    gradient: LinearGradient(
         colors: [
             Color(0xffCB00FE),
             Color(0xffFE0098),
             Color(0xffFF8A00),
          ],
     ),
   ),
),
```

Comment: Can you include your current snippet that you;ve tried so far? Also  point the specific part so that others can get easily

Comment: Check eamirho3ein's answer, it may solve in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
              top: 100,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(100),
                  ),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topRight,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [
                      Colors.purple,
                      Colors.pink,
                      Colors.orange,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )),
          Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 150,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 150,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]